# W3c validator recursive

Tags: hyperlink, w3c-validation

When we use http://validator.w3.org/checklink to check our links, one option is whether or not you use recursion. How does this option work?

Answer (score 0):

The w3c validator will follow the links in your site, and from there it will follow all the links again (depending on what you specify)

Comment: Hi Jonas, Thanks for response... could you please explains exactly what is the use of the check box Check linked documents recursively, recursion depth: in the site http://validator.w3.org/checklink